# DataFrame filtering by datatime column off

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have setup two dataframes and attempted to filter the results by moving a datetime object column to the index, and using .last('7D') to pull the entries whose datetime is 'stamped' within the last seven days. It worked for the first dataframe, but not the second. I have tried a variety of variations to filter the df to get what I need, but cannot get accurate output. I'm at a loss! This has been built iterative as well, so if you see some refactoring opportunities, let me know.

**Original DataFrame:** `engagements`

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> 
RangeIndex: 2572 entries, 0 to 2571 
Data columns (total 15 columns):
REQ_NAME                2572 non-null object
REQ_ID                  2572 non-null object
STATUS                  2572 non-null object
full_name               2572 non-null object
BIZ_UNIT                2572 non-null object
COMPLEXITY              2378 non-null object
PRIORITY                2390 non-null object
OPEN_DATE               2572 non-null datetime64[ns]
REQ_DATE                2572 non-null object
REQ_CAT                 2572 non-null object
REQ_NOTE                2572 non-null object
CostCenter              2572 non-null int64 
TargetCompletionDate    2572 non-null object 
UpdateDTTM              2514 non-null datetime64[ns] 
age                     2572 non-null timedelta64[ns] 
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), int64(1), object(11), timedelta64[ns](1) 
memory usage: 301.5+ KB
```

**Separating DataFrame**:

```
active_engagements = engagements[engagements['STATUS'].isin(active_status)]
comp_engagements = engagements[engagements['STATUS'].isin(comp_status)]
```

**First Filter**:

```
act_eng_open_lw = active engagements.set_index('OPEN_DATE')
act_eng_open_lw = act_eng_open_lw.last('7D')
```

*Output is the 10 rows of data I expect to see*

**Problem Child DataFrame**:

```
act_eng_comp_lw = comp_engagements.set_index('UpdateDTTM')
act_eng_comp_lw = act_eng_comp_lw.last('7D')
```

*Output is 105 rows, where I would expect 32*

**Info calls on both filtered DFs**: `act_eng_open_lw`:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> 
DatetimeIndex: 10 entries, 2019-12-20 to 2019-12-26
Data columns (total 14 columns): 
REQ_NAME                10 non-null object 
REQ_ID                  10 non-null object 
STATUS                  10 non-null object 
full_name               10 non-null object 
BIZ_UNIT                10 non-null object 
COMPLEXITY              5 non-null object 
PRIORITY                5 non-null object 
REQ_DATE                10 non-null object 
REQ_CAT                 10 non-null object 
REQ_NOTE                10 non-null object 
CostCenter              10 non-null int64 
TargetCompletionDate    10 non-null object 
UpdateDTTM              5 non-null datetime64[ns] 
age                     10 non-null timedelta64[ns] 
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1), object(11), timedelta64[ns](1) 
memory usage: 1.2+ KB
```

*act_eng_comp_lw*

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> 
DatetimeIndex: 105 entries, 2019-12-26 to 2019-11-27
Data columns (total 14 columns): 
REQ_NAME                105 non-null object 
REQ_ID                  105 non-null object 
STATUS                  105 non-null object 
full_name               105 non-null object 
BIZ_UNIT                105 non-null object 
COMPLEXITY              102 non-null object 
PRIORITY                104 non-null object 
OPEN_DATE               105 non-null datetime64[ns] 
REQ_DATE                105 non-null object 
REQ_CAT                 105 non-null object 
REQ_NOTE                105 non-null object 
CostCenter              105 non-null int64 
TargetCompletionDate    105 non-null object 
age                     105 non-null int64 
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(2), object(11) 
memory usage: 12.3+ KB
```

**Question**: Using the same filter, why is one Datetime column filtering properly with `.last` and the other is not?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the method I was using to catch the last 7 days, versus `.last`:

`act_eng_open_lw = act_eng_open_lw[act_eng_open_lw.index > dt.datetime.now() - pd.to_timedelta("7day")]`

This method works on both of my dataframes effectively.